# Download a file from a server

Tags: php, header, download

At the current time I'm using this code to output a file to a user.

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$or.'');
readfile($file);
```

The code, however doesn't tell the browser how large the file is. And it can't output large files like 1 gb. I want the code to tell the browser the actual size of the file and be able to output large files

Comment: What? That's not copy paste, I really mean it.

Comment: Have a look at `Content-length` and `Range`, see [here](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/http11).

Comment: Can you give more details on not handling a 1G file? It should be fine, so long as your file system supports it. What OS and FS format are you on?

Comment: Ah right, of course - `readfile` is trying to load the whole thing into RAM. OK, remove `readfile`, and instead open the file, and send it out in chunks manually.

Comment: Windows. The error is: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Out of memory. Found some info on webb, and they said that I need to change memory_limit to higher but the problem is you can't set for higher than 128 mb.

Comment: @halfer how do I do that? Are trying to find on google but no luck yet. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, use `fopen()` to open a file, `fread()` inside a loop to get and echo data bit by bit, and `fclose()` to close a file. Use the PHP manual thus: php.net/keyword-here.

Comment: Also, see [my post here](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/07/bandwidth-project-offering-direct-downloads-without-breaking-limits/), in particular the `download` controller class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
header("Content-Length: $value");
```

Answer (score 1):

For large files, you need to use chunked transfer. In most cases the underlying web server (Apach/Nginx/WHY) will have facilities to do that. I recommend you use them.

That way your code does not take up a worker thread for ages, and the run-away timer will not cut in in the middle of your down-load (which would upset your users).

btw - You are talking about file download, not upload - that would be user to server. Your tag is wrong.

Comment: Ian, you can edit posts if you like - retag if you see something that's misclassified. However in this case, I beat you to it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`readfile()` will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with `ob_get_level()`.